# Ubuntu 11.10 and Compiz Config

Tags: compiz

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)

I have clean installed 11.10 on my PC. When I am configuring compiz with CConfig (from ubuntu software center), GTK and all panels disappears. Don't you know solving or just compiz alternative to create pretty interface on my linux?

Answer (score 0):

[http://ubuntuguide.net/](http://ubuntuguide.net/enable-compiz-desktop-cube-in-ubuntu-11-10-oneiric-unity)

I tested it.
It's working properly.

Desktop cube, reset or other options available..

Ex:

```
rm -rf .gconf/apps/compiz*
rm -rf .cache/compizconfig-1/
rm -rf .config/compiz-1/
rm -rf .compiz*
```